# UIAutomation - tap cell of tableview - slow

Tags: ios, instruments, ui-automation

This UIAutomation script taps the 4th cell in a tableview. However, it takes around 30 seconds to complete.

```
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()[0].cells()[3].tap();
```

Is it typically so slow? If not, what could be causing the problem and are there any suggestions on speeding it up?

Comment: What's the value of `target.timeout()`?